# Do not render component when route is equal to /:id

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to return `null` for my `Navigation` component when my screen width is wide enough.

```js
if (!user.uid && pathname == "/" && !isTallEnough) return null;
  if (!user.uid && pathname === "/search" && !isTallEnough) return null;
```

Now, when I have a route for a username such as `/alex` or `/ryan` the conditional
doesn't work:

```js
  if (!user.uid && pathname === "/:id" && !isTallEnough) return null;
```

Comment: Are you using react router? Seems for me that `pathname` will be `/alex` instead of `/:id` so it will never match.

Comment: @SantiagoMendozaRamirez, Yes, I'm using react router. The pathname /alex would be entered in as a url, it's not an actual route in my app like "/" and "/search"

Comment: I know. But where are this validations? I mean, if you `console.log(pathname)` before those validations, what does it prints?